# C# Show DataGridView based on the combobox selection

Tags: c#, winforms

I need help with my C# windows form application.

I have one DataGridView created in my form, the DataGridView needs to only show depending of the users comobobox selection, the combobox has three selection and each selection needs to show a different database table for example if they selection warehouse1 then will show the database table from warehouse1 database. if they selection warehouse2 then will show the database table warehouse2 and same thing for warehouse3.

each warehouse if different database. so far I have it working when just adding the warehouse1 without the combobox selection, but I need to be based on the combobox selection.

after creating the each function to the get database table will be called in the form1 method for each database

here is my code

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Bind the DataGridView to the BindingSource
            // and load the data from the database.

            if (cmb_DatabaseSelection.SelectedItem == "warehouse1")
            {
                dataGridView_ShowAllData.DataSource = bindingSource;

                GetLeMarsConnectionDatabaseConnection("Select * from dbo.AllInvoicesInReadyStatus");
            }

            if (cmb_DatabaseSelection.SelectedItem == "warehouse2")
            {
                dataGridView_ShowAllData.DataSource = bindingSource;

                GetLeMarsConnectionDatabaseConnection("Select * from dbo.AllInvoicesInReadyStatus");
            }

            if (cmb_DatabaseSelection.SelectedItem == "warehouse3")
            {
                dataGridView_ShowAllData.DataSource = bindingSource;

                GetLeMarsConnectionDatabaseConnection("Select * from dbo.AllInvoicesInReadyStatus");
            }



            this.rpt_CallSSRSReport.RefreshReport();

            CallReport();
        }


private void GetLeMarsConnectionDatabaseConnection(string selectCommand)
        {


            try
            {

                //Create the connection string, data adapter and data table.
                String connectionString = "database1";


                // Specify a connection string. Replace the given value with a 
                // database accessible to your system.

                // Create a new data adapter based on the specified query.
                dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);

                // Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and
                // delete commands based on selectCommand. These are used to
                // update the database.
                SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

                // Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
                System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
                table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                dataAdapter.Fill(table);
                bindingSource.DataSource = table;

                // Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.
                dataGridView_ShowAllData.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);

            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Database connection ERROR");
            }

        }

        private void GetSchuylerConnectionDatabaseConnection(string selectCommand)
        {
            try
            {

                //Create the connection string, data adapter and data table.
                String connectionString = "database2";


                // Specify a connection string. Replace the given value with a 
                // database accessible to your system.

                // Create a new data adapter based on the specified query.
                dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);

                // Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and
                // delete commands based on selectCommand. These are used to
                // update the database.
                SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

                // Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
                System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
                table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                dataAdapter.Fill(table);
                bindingSource.DataSource = table;

                // Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.
                dataGridView_ShowAllData.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);

            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Database connection ERROR");
            }

        }

        private void GetDetroitLakesConnectionDatabaseConnection(string selectCommand)
        {
            try
            {

                //Create the connection string, data adapter and data table.
                String connectionString = "database3";


                // Specify a connection string. Replace the given value with a 

                // database accessible to your system.

                // Create a new data adapter based on the specified query.
                dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);

                // Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and
                // delete commands based on selectCommand. These are used to
                // update the database.
                SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

                // Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
                System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
                table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                dataAdapter.Fill(table);
                bindingSource.DataSource = table;

                // Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.
                dataGridView_ShowAllData.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);

            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Database connection ERROR");
            }

        }
```

Comment: add event handler for `SelectedIndexChanged` event of your combobox and move the code from your `Form1_Load` method to that event handler

Comment: can you show me how to add that event handler, and would that work, i never done the event handler

Comment: double click combobox in your form designer and it will create a method something like `cmb_DatabaseSelection_SelectedIndexChanged`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Double Click on Combo box. Following code will appear in your code behind

```
    private void cmb_DatabaseSelection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

**or u can add event  like this as well**
[image]

**Add the following code to the above function (Code as per your needs)**

```
if (cmb_DatabaseSelection.SelectedItem == "warehouse1")
        {
            dataGridView_ShowAllData.DataSource = bindingSource;

            GetLeMarsConnectionDatabaseConnection("Select * from dbo.AllInvoicesInReadyStatus");
        }

        if (cmb_DatabaseSelection.SelectedItem == "warehouse2")
        {
            dataGridView_ShowAllData.DataSource = bindingSource;

            GetLeMarsConnectionDatabaseConnection("Select * from dbo.AllInvoicesInReadyStatus");
        }

        if (cmb_DatabaseSelection.SelectedItem == "warehouse3")
        {
            dataGridView_ShowAllData.DataSource = bindingSource;

            GetLeMarsConnectionDatabaseConnection("Select * from dbo.AllInvoicesInReadyStatus");
        }
```

Comment: I will try this, I will let you know the results.

Comment: Dude man, that worked thanks man you make it look easy I learned a lot with your suggestion, thanks man again.